# Calling a stored procedure in phpmyadmin from website to check login details

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to call a stored procedure in php-myadmin from wordpress website to check user login details.

I have a button that points to javascript function:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="checkloging()">
```

The javascript file contains ajax:

```
function checkloging() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'checklogin_php',
           data:{action:'call_this'},
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
           }

      });
 }
```

The ajax code is to call a php file:

```
<?php

//Call the proc() procedure follow
$result= mysql_query("CALL checkpassword('username', 'password');") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++)
    { 
        echo  $row[$i]."<br>";
    }  
}  
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

which invokes a stored procedure in phpmyadmin.

Please can any anyone help with this? I am not not sure if this is a good approach and I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: better use mysqli_query instead of mysql_query

Comment: and pls do connect to your database first before querying

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just an application to allow you to easier manage a MySQL or MariaDB database server; probably instead you mean one of those.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.
Note: Use and read more about mysqli

```
<?php 

  //connect to database
  $connection = mysqli_connect("hostname", "user", "password", "db");

  //call and run the store proc
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, 
     "CALL checkpassword") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

  //loop the result set
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
      echo $row[0] . " - " . + $row[1]; 
  }

  mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but where I'm having an issue is calling this from a button. Please help!